# Is there a best way to export from the Directory Utility?

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, smb

I want to export all of the data from a page in the MacOS directory utility. In the edit section, it say's I'm looking at Users in node `/Active Directory/XXXXX/All Domains`. It lists all the users I need, and the data. I have tried using `dsexport` in terminal, but the data seems to clip off at a random point.

If this is possible with or without 3rd party software

I have tried this command to export:

```bash
dsexport --N export.txt "/Active Directory/XXXXX/All Domains" dsRecTypeStandard:Users
```

Comment: I discovered that for some reason some record types ar e always excluded. https://unix.com/man-page/osx/1/dsexport